# POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data

Tags: file-upload, curl, go, multipart

I'm trying to upload images from my computer to a website using go. Usually, I use a bash script that sends a file and a key to the server:

```
curl -F "image"=@"IMAGEFILE" -F "key"="KEY" URL
```

it works fine, but I'm trying to convert this request into my golang program.

http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2013/07/01/golang-multipart-file-upload-example/

I tried this link and many others, but, for each code that I try, the response from the server is "no image sent", and I've no idea why. If someone knows what's happening with the example above.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223616/http-post-file-multipart-programming-in-go-language

Comment: You can use https://curlconverter.com/go/ to convert that curl command to Go

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Here's some sample code.

In short, you'll need to use the [`mime/multipart` package](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) to build the form.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    var client *http.Client
    var remoteURL string
    {
        //setup a mocked http client.
        ts := httptest.NewTLSServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            b, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("%s", b)
        }))
        defer ts.Close()
        client = ts.Client()
        remoteURL = ts.URL
    }

    //prepare the reader instances to encode
    values := map[string]io.Reader{
        "file":  mustOpen("main.go"), // lets assume its this file
        "other": strings.NewReader("hello world!"),
    }
    err := Upload(client, remoteURL, values)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func Upload(client *http.Client, url string, values map[string]io.Reader) (err error) {
    // Prepare a form that you will submit to that URL.
    var b bytes.Buffer
    w := multipart.NewWriter(&b)
    for key, r := range values {
        var fw io.Writer
        if x, ok := r.(io.Closer); ok {
            defer x.Close()
        }
        // Add an image file
        if x, ok := r.(*os.File); ok {
            if fw, err = w.CreateFormFile(key, x.Name()); err != nil {
                return
            }
        } else {
            // Add other fields
            if fw, err = w.CreateFormField(key); err != nil {
                return
            }
        }
        if _, err = io.Copy(fw, r); err != nil {
            return err
        }

    }
    // Don't forget to close the multipart writer.
    // If you don't close it, your request will be missing the terminating boundary.
    w.Close()

    // Now that you have a form, you can submit it to your handler.
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &b)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    // Don't forget to set the content type, this will contain the boundary.
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", w.FormDataContentType())

    // Submit the request
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Check the response
    if res.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        err = fmt.Errorf("bad status: %s", res.Status)
    }
    return
}

func mustOpen(f string) *os.File {
    r, err := os.Open(f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return r
}
```

Comment: Good sample code. One thing is missing: some web servers such as Django check part's "Content-Type" header. Here's how to set that header: 
<pre>
 partHeader := textproto.MIMEHeader{}
 disp := fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="data"; filename="%s"`, fn)
 partHeader.Add("Content-Disposition", disp)
 partHeader.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
 part, err := writer.CreatePart(partHeader)
</pre>

Comment: Works well except the `file.Name()` is not working for me. Seems like it returns the filepath as passed to os.Open() not a name... `(string) (len=37) "./internal/file_example_JPG_500kB.jpg"` `// Name returns the name of the file as presented to Open.
func (f *File) Name() string { return f.name }` If I hardcode the filename in `w.CreateFormFile()` it works fine. Thanks Attila

Comment: Sorry, what if our values is like map[string][]string ?

Comment: You open the file in the `mustOpen()` but don't close it. Should you close the file after you are done with it with e.g. `defer file.Close()` ?

Comment: @lion_bash that is true; in hindsight, this is some pretty terrible code I wrote here almost ten years ago. You're welcome to suggest edits though, you seem to have the reputation to do so :)

Comment: this is also example of how to "not" write clean code ...

Comment: You just saved me! With this comment
`// Don't forget to close the multipart writer.
// If you don't close it, your request will be missing the terminating boundary.
w.Close()`. I've searched for 5 hours solution, why server returning me "The file was only partially uploaded".. I hate go in such moments..

Answer (score 15):

Here's a function I've used that uses `io.Pipe()` to avoid reading in the entire file to memory or needing to manage any buffers. It handles only a single file, but could easily be extended to handle more by adding more parts within the goroutine. The happy path works well. The error paths have not hand much testing.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "mime/multipart"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func UploadMultipartFile(client *http.Client, uri, key, path string) (*http.Response, error) {
    body, writer := io.Pipe()

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, uri, body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    mwriter := multipart.NewWriter(writer)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", mwriter.FormDataContentType())

    errchan := make(chan error)

    go func() {
        defer close(errchan)
        defer writer.Close()
        defer mwriter.Close()

        w, err := mwriter.CreateFormFile(key, path)
        if err != nil {
            errchan <- err
            return
        }

        in, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            errchan <- err
            return
        }
        defer in.Close()

        if written, err := io.Copy(w, in); err != nil {
            errchan <- fmt.Errorf("error copying %s (%d bytes written): %v", path, written, err)
            return
        }

        if err := mwriter.Close(); err != nil {
            errchan <- err
            return
        }
    }()

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    merr := <-errchan

    if err != nil || merr != nil {
        return resp, fmt.Errorf("http error: %v, multipart error: %v", err, merr)
    }

    return resp, nil
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Here's [my code](https://github.com/FiveIT/eseuri/blob/5ea0a5da6eccb18b02447bddf265bd0ad0099fee/pkg/request/multipart.go#L24-L83), maybe I did something wrong. Using a `bytes.Buffer` and creating the form before making the request as in the accepted answer worked.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an option that works for files or strings:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "io"
   "mime/multipart"
   "os"
   "strings"
)

func createForm(form map[string]string) (string, io.Reader, error) {
   body := new(bytes.Buffer)
   mp := multipart.NewWriter(body)
   defer mp.Close()
   for key, val := range form {
      if strings.HasPrefix(val, "@") {
         val = val[1:]
         file, err := os.Open(val)
         if err != nil { return "", nil, err }
         defer file.Close()
         part, err := mp.CreateFormFile(key, val)
         if err != nil { return "", nil, err }
         io.Copy(part, file)
      } else {
         mp.WriteField(key, val)
      }
   }
   return mp.FormDataContentType(), body, nil
}
```

Example:

```
package main
import "net/http"

func main() {
   form := map[string]string{"image": "@IMAGEFILE", "key": "KEY"}
   ct, body, err := createForm(form)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   http.Post("https://stackoverflow.com", ct, body)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart#Writer.WriteField

Comment: Do you read the file from the Disk? What if i have an image byte and i want to upload that?

Answer (score 6):

After having to decode the accepted answer for this question for use in my unit testing I finally ended up with the follow refactored code:

```
func createMultipartFormData(t *testing.T, fieldName, fileName string) (bytes.Buffer, *multipart.Writer) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    var err error
    w := multipart.NewWriter(&b)
    var fw io.Writer
    file := mustOpen(fileName)
    if fw, err = w.CreateFormFile(fieldName, file.Name()); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error creating writer: %v", err)
    }
    if _, err = io.Copy(fw, file); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error with io.Copy: %v", err)
    }
    w.Close()
    return b, w
}

func mustOpen(f string) *os.File {
    r, err := os.Open(f)
    if err != nil {
        pwd, _ := os.Getwd()
        fmt.Println("PWD: ", pwd)
        panic(err)
    }
    return r
}
```

Now it should be pretty easy to use:

```
    b, w := createMultipartFormData(t, "image","../luke.png")

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &b)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    // Don't forget to set the content type, this will contain the boundary.
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", w.FormDataContentType())
```

Answer (score 1):

Send file from one service to another:

```
func UploadFile(network, uri string, f multipart.File, h *multipart.FileHeader) error {

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)

    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file", h.Filename)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }

    b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }

    part.Write(b)
    writer.Close()

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, buf)

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    b, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if resp.StatusCode >= 400 {
        return errors.New(string(b))
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on what your code does (including comments), as that would make it useful as a resource, and not just as an answer tailored to a specific question.

Answer (score -1):

To extend on @attila-o answer, here is the code I went with to perform a POST HTTP req in Go with:

- 1 file
- configurable file name (f.Name() didn't work)
- extra form fields.

Curl representation:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:9091/storage/add \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F owner=0xc916Cfe5c83dD4FC3c3B0Bf2ec2d4e401782875e \
  -F password=$PWD \
  -F file=@./internal/file_example_JPG_500kB.jpg
```

Go way:

```golang
client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
    }
req, err := createStoragePostReq(cfg)
res, err := executeStoragePostReq(client, req)


func createStoragePostReq(cfg Config) (*http.Request, error) {
    extraFields := map[string]string{
        "owner": "0xc916cfe5c83dd4fc3c3b0bf2ec2d4e401782875e",
        "password": "pwd",
    }

    url := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:%d%s", cfg.HttpServerConfig().Port(), lethstorage.AddRoute)
    b, w, err := createMultipartFormData("file","./internal/file_example_JPG_500kB.jpg", "file_example_JPG_500kB.jpg", extraFields)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &b)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", w.FormDataContentType())

    return req, nil
}

func executeStoragePostReq(client *http.Client, req *http.Request) (lethstorage.AddRes, error) {
    var addRes lethstorage.AddRes

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return addRes, err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return addRes, err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &addRes)
    if err != nil {
        return addRes, err
    }

    return addRes, nil
}

func createMultipartFormData(fileFieldName, filePath string, fileName string, extraFormFields map[string]string) (b bytes.Buffer, w *multipart.Writer, err error) {
    w = multipart.NewWriter(&b)
    var fw io.Writer
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)

    if fw, err = w.CreateFormFile(fileFieldName, fileName); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if _, err = io.Copy(fw, file); err != nil {
        return
    }

    for k, v := range extraFormFields {
        w.WriteField(k, v)
    }

    w.Close()

    return
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I have found [this tutorial](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/04.5.html) very helpful to clarify my confusions about file uploading in Go.

Basically you upload the file via ajax using `form-data` on a client and use the following small snippet of Go code on the server:

```
file, handler, err := r.FormFile("img") // img is the key of the form-data
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer file.Close()

fmt.Println("File is good")
fmt.Println(handler.Filename)
fmt.Println()
fmt.Println(handler.Header)


f, err := os.OpenFile(handler.Filename, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
defer f.Close()
io.Copy(f, file)
```

Here `r` is `*http.Request`. **P.S.** this just stores the file in the same folder and does not perform any security checks.

Comment: OP was asking how to *POST a file with Go* (HTTP client), not accept and handle a file POSTed from a webpage in Go (HTTP server).