# How can you upload files as a []byte in go?

Tags: http, go, upload

I would like to use golang post request, upload pictures, but I do not want to pass filepath, just want to pass [] byte
The following article are not what I need because they are used os.Open
[golang POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205796/golang-post-data-using-the-content-type-multipart-form-data)

```
func Upload(url, file string) (err error) {
    // Prepare a form that you will submit to that URL.
    var b bytes.Buffer
    w := multipart.NewWriter(&b)
    // Add your image file
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return 
    }
    defer f.Close()
    fw, err := w.CreateFormFile("image", file)
    if err != nil {
        return 
    }
    if _, err = io.Copy(fw, f); err != nil {
        return
    }
    // Add the other fields
    if fw, err = w.CreateFormField("key"); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if _, err = fw.Write([]byte("KEY")); err != nil {
        return
    }
    // Don't forget to close the multipart writer.
    // If you don't close it, your request will be missing the terminating boundary.
    w.Close()

    // Now that you have a form, you can submit it to your handler.
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &b)
    if err != nil {
        return 
    }
    // Don't forget to set the content type, this will contain the boundary.
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", w.FormDataContentType())

    // Submit the request
    client := &http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return 
    }

    // Check the response
    if res.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        err = fmt.Errorf("bad status: %s", res.Status)
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: The http.request.Body() is a byte stream, maybe your question belongs to the client side, where does these images come from? A website or some other client?

Comment: My request is such that the frontend and api(api1) is separated, the frontend to pass a base64 parameters, in the api(api1): This parameter will be converted to [] byte, and then call another api（api2）by http post

Comment: Here are the parameters I requested

--8D4A8ED669208A7
Content-Disposition:form-data;name="charset"
Content-Type:text/plain

utf-8
--8D4A8ED669208A7
Content-Disposition:form-data;name="sign"
Content-Type:text/plain

Qlv1mjWGUEq+7i2FhTGjCa7WwFcZBHlg019JrHgjNJ2D98bEnkHKI9A+scHm+xaewgaqC2i73lybrRNwzUpKJFlUoVcrnFhuMWbHCI73Zkg+mn8lLJrzMgoqPBTsMxze+0uDCci7cmpM8ijTMKaxtwWddg910EzDMkQra14TiU4=
--8D4A8ED669208A7
Content-Disposition:form-data;name="image_content";filename="123.jpg"
Content-Type:image/jpeg

Comment: I expect like this: if _, err = io.Copy(fw, []byte); err != nil {
        return
    }

Comment: The answer is already in the sample code, i.e. instead of `io.Copy(fw, f)`, write directly using `fw.Write(your-data)`.

Comment: you are right，@putu

Comment: I mark answer in another article：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302374/can-i-post-with-content-type-multipart-form-data-in-go

Answer (score 1):

Since you use

```
if _, err = io.Copy(fw, f); err != nil {
    return
}
```

You may as well edit your code to:

1. Add new import: `"bytes"`
2. Change the method signature to `func Upload(url string, file []byte) (err error)`
3. Use `io.Copy(fw, bytes.NewReader(f))`