# Can I post with Content-Type: multipart/form-data

Tags: http, go

How do I POST to an API with Content-Type: multipart/form-data, []byte parameters and string arguments? I have tried, but it is failing.

Error message:

```
details: "[301 301 Moved Permanently]<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\r\n<html>\r\n301 Moved Permanently\r\n<body bgcolor=\"white\">\r\n301 Moved Permanently\r\n<p>The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI.</p >\r\n<hr/>Powered by Tengine/2.1.0</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

Go code:

```
func NewPost2(url string) ([]byte, error) {
    m := make(map[string]interface{}, 0)
    m["fileName"] ="good"
    m["name"] = Base64ToByte("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")
b, _ := json.Marshal(m)

    httpReq, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(b))
    httpReq.Header.Set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(httpReq)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode < 200 || resp.StatusCode >= 300 {
        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("[%d %s]%s", resp.StatusCode, resp.Status, string(b))
    }

    respData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return respData, nil
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now, I am very happy with the mood to share my solution

```
func NewPostFile(url string, paramTexts map[string]interface{}, paramFile FileItem) ([]byte, error) {
// if paramFiles ==nil {
//  return NewPost(url,paramTexts,header,transport)
// }

bodyBuf := &bytes.Buffer{}
bodyWriter := multipart.NewWriter(bodyBuf)

for k, v := range paramTexts {
    bodyWriter.WriteField(k, v.(string))
}
fileWriter, err := bodyWriter.CreateFormFile(paramFile.Key, paramFile.FileName)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    //fmt.Println("Create form file error: ", error)
    return nil, err
}
fileWriter.Write(paramFile.Content)
contentType := bodyWriter.FormDataContentType()
bodyWriter.Close()
fmt.Println(bodyBuf.String())

resp, err := http.Post(url, contentType, bodyBuf)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
fmt.Println(resp)

if resp.StatusCode < 200 || resp.StatusCode >= 300 {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("[%d %s]%s", resp.StatusCode, resp.Status, string(b))
}
respData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
fmt.Println(string(respData))
return respData, nil
```

}

```
type FileItem struct {
Key      string //image_content
FileName string //test.jpg
Content  []byte //[]byte
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped the multipart code in a function, as you need to `Close` it before you
can make a request. Also my method is using `@` as a heuristic, similar to
cURL [1]:

```
package main

import (
   "bytes"
   "io"
   "mime/multipart"
   "os"
   "strings"
)

func createForm(form map[string]string) (string, io.Reader, error) {
   body := new(bytes.Buffer)
   mp := multipart.NewWriter(body)
   defer mp.Close()
   for key, val := range form {
      if strings.HasPrefix(val, "@") {
         val = val[1:]
         file, err := os.Open(val)
         if err != nil { return "", nil, err }
         defer file.Close()
         part, err := mp.CreateFormFile(key, val)
         if err != nil { return "", nil, err }
         io.Copy(part, file)
      } else {
         mp.WriteField(key, val)
      }
   }
   return mp.FormDataContentType(), body, nil
}
```

Example:

```
package main
import "net/http"

func main() {
   form := map[string]string{"profile": "@portrait.jpg", "name": "John"}
   ct, body, err := createForm(form)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   http.Post("https://stackoverflow.com", ct, body)
}
```

1. https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F

Answer (score 0):

On a 301 response, the new url is specified in the *headers* of the response, not its body

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

try printing :

```
resp.Header["Location"]
```

---

If you have this error as a final response, this also means that the `http.Client` chose to not follow this redirection.

The [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.CheckRedirect) says that the dafult policy for a Client is to follow up to 10 redirects.

In order to debug redirects, you can write your own `CheckRedirect` function, which can for instance print the sequence of urls

Comment: So, I think it is because I asked the parameters of the format is wrong, how should I set my parameters

Comment: I can find this error,but But this page did not give me more help information，https://openapi.alipay.com/home/error.htm

Comment: Does the response have a `Location: [url]` header ?

Comment: all resp：&{301 Moved Permanently 301 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Connection:[keep-alive] Location:[https://openapi.alipay.com/home/error.htm] Set-Cookie:[spanner=;path=/;secure;] Server:[Tengine/2.1.0] Date:[Thu, 01 Jun 2017 09:08:31 GMT] Content-Type:[text/html] Content-Length:[284]] 0xc042006480 284 [] false false map[] 0xc0421ae000 <nil>}

Comment: I think the focus is not 301, but how is the parameters passed