# Converting curl -F to golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to convert the mailgun curl command for sending email to golang. This is the original curl:

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0' \ 
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/messages \
 -F from='Excited User <excited@samples.mailgun.org>' \
 -F to='devs@mailgun.net' \
 -F subject='Hello' \
 -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
```

Updated code:

```
    var b bytes.Buffer
    w := multipart.NewWriter(&b)
    fw, err := w.CreateFormField("from")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    _, err = fw.Write([]byte("Excited User <excited@samples.mailgun.org>"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fw, err = w.CreateFormField("to")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    _, err = fw.Write([]byte("devs@mailgun.net"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fw, err = w.CreateFormField("subject")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    _, err = fw.Write([]byte("Hello"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    fw, err = w.CreateFormField("text")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    _, err = fw.Write([]byte("Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    w.Close()

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/messages", &b)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    req.SetBasicAuth("api", "key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0")

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", w.FormDataContentType())
    // req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Printf("Resp: %s\n", resp)
```

I have of course changed `api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0`, `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/samples.mailgun.org/messages` and `devs@mailgun.net` to my own API and email address, but it doesn't seem to  work..

Could someone please take a look to see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: For sending mail (as opposed to learning `net/http`) you might want Mailgun's Go SDK: https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-go

Comment: @twotwotwo yeah thanks, I saw the package before, but I felt like it would be good to learn how to convert the curl command both because of future use but also because the package seems to ask for different info

Answer (score 1):

Option `-F` send a multipart field according to CURL documentation:

`-F, --form CONTENT  Specify HTTP multipart POST data (H)`

This can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20397167/1786696

Comment: I updated the code based on your comment, could you please take a look?