# Sending Multipart request with curl usign GoLang

Tags: curl, go, multipartform-data

I want to convert below code to golang.

```
curl -X POST
  'https://api.documo.com/v1/fax/send' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic YOUR_API_KEY' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'recipientFax=12345678900' \
  -F 'coverPage=false' \
  -F 'recipientName=John' \
  -F 'subject=test' \
  -F 'notes=test' \
  -F '=@/home/user/Documents/Sample.pdf'
```

Please help

Below is my code what i have tried.

```
func SendFaxDocumo(files []*multipart.FileHeader, params map[string]string) {

    request, err := SendMultipartRequest("https://api.documo.com/v1/fax/send", params, files)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())

    }
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        body := &bytes.Buffer{}
        _, err := body.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        resp.Body.Close()
        fmt.Println(resp.StatusCode)
        fmt.Println(resp.Header)
        fmt.Println(body)
    }
}

func SendMultipartRequest(uri string, params map[string]string, files []*multipart.FileHeader) (*http.Request, error) {

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    for i, _ := range files {
        // string_index := strconv.Itoa(i)
        file, err := files[i].Open()
        defer file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        doc , err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err,980)
        }

        part, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file",files[i].Filename)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        part.Write([]byte(string(doc)))
        if _, err = io.Copy(part, file); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    for key, val := range params {
        _ = writer.WriteField(key, val)
    }

    err := writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic my_key")

    return req, err
}
```

And the error i am getting is below:
{"error":{"name":"Error","message":"File extension not allowed. Allowed formats: tiff,gif,png,jpeg,pdf,doc,xls,ppt,pcl,eps,ps,txt,rtf,xml,fxc,docx,pptx,xlsx"}}

This is the response got from the url requested even if i am trying it by pdf.

Comment: You don't seem to have tried anything. Please show what you have attempted and what did not work. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Marc i have added what you are asking, please check

Comment: Instead of how you send the request we are more interested in how you genreate the request in `SendMultipartRequest`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205796/post-data-using-the-content-type-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a long few days researching the same problem. After using `httputil.DumpRequest` to view what data I was actually passing to Documo, I saw that the content-type header for the file field was set to `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`. This is set by the `CreateFormFile` method you're using. See the [multipart pkg](https://golang.org/src/mime/multipart/writer.go?s=3374:3452#L130) for the source code.

The `octet-stream` subtype is used as a default for binary files or files that need to be opened in an application. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#applicationoctet-stream), [IANA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#applicationoctet-stream), or [this awesome explanation](https://kb.iu.edu/d/agtj).

The problem, as far as I understand it, is that **Documo expects us to explicitly tell them what type of file we're sending them** so they know how to handle the rendering. So for my case, `octet-stream` didn't tell them anything. Switching the file content-type to `application/pdf` did the trick.

### Solution

Instead of calling `writer.CreateFormField`, I basically copied the three lines from the source code of `CreateFormFile` and hard coded the `Content-Type` to header to `application/pdf` instead of `application/octet-stream` (Note: my service only deals with PDF right now, so you may need to adjust this if your files are different types).

Code:

```golang
func SendMultipartRequest(uri string, params map[string]string, files []*multipart.FileHeader) (*http.Request, error) {

    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)

    for i, _ := range files {
        file, err := files[i].Open()
        defer file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // replace create CreateFormFile with this
        h := make(textproto.MIMEHeader) // import "net/textproto"
        h.Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="file"; filename="%s"`, files[i].Filename)
        h.Set("Content-Type", "application/pdf") // this is where you'll set your document type(s)
        fileWriter, err := form.CreatePart(h)
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, file); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    for key, val := range params {
        _ = writer.WriteField(key, val)
    }

    err := writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", uri, body)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic my_key")

    return req, err
}
```

It's not the sexiest solution but I'm finally able to send complete documents through Documo now.

Hope this helps.