# Go post a file with nested object field

Tags: go, post

I need to POST the following curl command using Go

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/routes/route_name -F "name=function" -F "config.file[1]=@my_file.lua"
```

I have been looking into multipart file upload [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205796/post-data-using-the-content-type-multipart-form-data), but I can't wrap my head around how to create a post with a nested field name (`config.file` is a config object with file as an array of strings) using `CreateFormFile(key, val)`.

The problem I am having is according to the docs (https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Writer.WriteField) the WriteField API takes a field name and a value (path to file to post). I am not sure how to post a field name that is in a nested object e.g. `CreateFormFile("config.file", filePath)`.

Anyone know how to convert the above curl command to Go using POST.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205796/post-data-using-the-content-type-multipart-form-data seems pretty complete example... please write some code and show us what you tried and where it went wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205796/post-data-using-the-content-type-multipart-form-data)

Comment: So according to the docs (https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#Writer.WriteField) the WriteField API takes a fieldname and a value (path to file to post). I am not sure how to post a fieldname that is in a nested object e.g. `CreateFormFile("config.file", filePath)`. The examples that are given seem to only cover cases of a flat object where the key is in the root level of the object, whereas I want to post the key that is in a nested value which is what the title of this question indicates.