# golang POST image and text field with multipart/form-data

Tags: go, multipartform-data

Yes, I have found answers:

http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2013/07/01/golang-multipart-file-upload-example/

[golang POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205796/golang-post-data-using-the-content-type-multipart-form-data)

[HTTP-POST file multipart programming in Go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223616/http-post-file-multipart-programming-in-go-language)

And answers not helpful, because I'm get error with multipart.NewWriter. 
My version of go lang 1.3.3

I'm trying to send some text data and image with form(templates/form.html)

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
          <label>Image
            <input type="file" name="Image" class="button"/>
          </label>
        </div>

     </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">
          <label>About Me
            <textarea type="text" name="aboutMySelf" class="aboutMySelf"></textarea>
          </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my Go approach is like this:

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/textproto"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/schema"

)



func render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, context map[string]interface{}) {
    tmpl_list := []string{fmt.Sprintf("templates/%s.html", tmpl)}
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl_list...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("template parsing error: ", err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(w, context)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("template executing error: ", err)
    }
}
    type FileHeader struct {
        Filename string
        Header   textproto.MIMEHeader
        // contains filtered or unexported fields
    }
     func uploadImage(q *http.Request, nameInForm string) {
        q.ParseMultipartForm(32 << 20)

        file, _, err := q.FormFile(nameInForm)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)

        }
        defer file.Close()

        f, err := os.OpenFile("./static/uploadimages/"+handler.Filename+".jpg", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0666)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)

        }
        defer f.Close()
        io.Copy(f, file)
    }
func main() {

    rtr := mux.NewRouter()



    //ADMIN SECTION
    rtr.HandleFunc("/myself", myself).Methods("GET")
    rtr.HandleFunc("/myself", myselfP).Methods("POST")


    rtr.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")))

    http.Handle("/", rtr)

    log.Println("Listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
func myself(w http.ResponseWriter, q *http.Request) {

    render(w,"form",nil)

}
func myselfP(w http.ResponseWriter, q *http.Request) {
    err := q.ParseForm()

    if err != nil {
        // Handle error
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    uploadImage(q, "Image")


    http.Redirect(w, q, "/myself", http.StatusFound)

}
```

File uploads perfectly, but I cann't get data from textarea. I'm trying understand what different between simple form with fields and multipart form, and how I can get data from fields

Thanks and regards

Comment: Maybe you could condens your code to what actually doesn't work. I understand that file uploads works, but textarea input not. But your Go code never tries to read the textarea data? What's wrong with Request.Form or Request.FormValue?

Comment: @ Volker q.Formvalue("aboutMySelf") output empty string. I think in multipart form I need something else, if I want to get data from textarea

Comment: Make sure you do q.Formvalue("aboutMySelf") **after** calling ParseMultipartForm.

Comment: @Volker Yes! ParseMultipartForm(). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can get a **multipart.Part** from **multipart.Reader**. The **Part.FileName()** will be empty if the parameter is not a File. You can get the reader by calling **r.MultipartReader()**. Once you get the reader the following code will get you array of Files and map of other fields.

```
func ReadFormData(mr *multipart.Reader) ([]FileParam, map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var part *multipart.Part
    var err error
    paramFiles := []FileParam{}
    paramTexts := map[string]interface{}{}
    for {
        if part, err = mr.NextPart(); err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF { //io.EOF error means reading is complete
                return paramFiles, paramTexts, fmt.Errorf(" error reading multipart request: %+v", err)
            }
            break
        }

        if part.FileName() != "" {
            content, err := readFileParam(part)
            if err != nil {
                return paramFiles, paramTexts, fmt.Errorf(" error reading file param %s: %+v", part.FileName, err)
            }

            fileItem := FileParam{
                Key:      "configFiles",
                FileName: part.FileName(),
                Content:  content,
            }
            paramFiles = append(paramFiles, fileItem)
        } else {
            name := part.FormName()
            value := readValueFromFormData(part)
            paramTexts[name] = value
        }

    }
    return paramFiles, paramTexts, nil
}

func readValueFromFormData(part *multipart.Part) string {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(part)
    return buf.String()
}

func readFileParam(part *multipart.Part) ([]byte, error) {
    content := []byte{}
    uploaded := false
    var err error

    for !uploaded {
        chunk := make([]byte, 4096)
        if _, err = part.Read(chunk); err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf(" error reading multipart file %+v", err)
            }
            uploaded = true
        }
        content = append(content, chunk...)
    }

    return content, nil
}

type FileParam struct {
    Key      string
    FileName string
    Content  []byte
}
```